# placing read data from file into record

Tags: java, record, java.util.scanner

I have a record for employees. Six fields long, with things such as

```
private String name;
private String id;
private double salary;
```

I need to read the raw data from a .txt file containing 18 lines of data for three different employees (6 lines per employee), and place the data into a specific employee record. So far, this is what I have in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //employee declarations
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    Employee e2 = new Employee();
    Employee e3 = new Employee();
    int count = 0;
    int emp_count = 0;

    File in_file = new File("EmployeeData.txt");
    Scanner fscan = new Scanner(in_file);

    while(fscan.hasNext())
    {
        e1.set_name
```

not quite sure how to get the appropriate line of data from the txt file into its corresponding slot in an employee record. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a counter to track no of times, your while loop has run.. Then move to another while.. Oh, but that will be a problem too, because you are having different attributes in different lines..

Comment: If you were working through the problem manually how would you decide which row of data belonged to which employee? A snippet of the data file may help with some more useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate function which only read one Employee record at a time

```
public static Employee readEmployeeData(Scanner scanner) {

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    if (scanner.hasNext())
        employee.name = scanner.next();//Use getter setters
    if (scanner.hasNext())
        employee.id = scanner.next();
    if (scanner.hasNextDouble())
        employee.salary = scanner.nextDouble();
    else
        scanner.next();// For double case

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: I think I've decided to dump all the raw data from the .txt file into an array, and then use the native indexing to navigate between lines and employee records. More info to come as I work through the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflect for the fields of Employee class, which may be represented as a array or something. After the array is filled with everything, you can change into another object to fill.

The only question is that, the order of data in txt file same is the same as the field list of the object. There may be something you should do to adjust the order between the field in object and the data line in txt file.